# Extraction operator override for a particular expected pattern

Tags: c++

How can I override the extraction operator so it gives values to several variables with a particular expected pattern? And it should trigger the `failbit` if the input doesn't match that expected pattern.

For instance, I want to overload the operator for a `Date` class, so when the user inputs a date following the format `dd/mm/yyyy` the overriden method would split that input and assign the day, month and year to three different local `int` variables, and then assign them to the attributes of the class, which would also be `int`.

How can I split a single input using `istream`? How can I check the input follows the pattern?

Also very important, how could I prevent the user from falling into an infinite loop if the input is not correct? Given the situation that the program asks for the user's input in an infinite loop that would only finish when a good object is built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the foundation, overloading the **extraction** operator.  *(Note: extraction operator extracts from a stream, input, and an insertion operator inserts into a stream, output.)*

```
class Date
{
  unsigned int m_year;
  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Date& d);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Date& d)
{
  // Read Date data members here
  inp >> d.m_year;
  return inp; // To allow chaining.
}
```

With the foundation in place, the next step is to come up with a scheme for telling the `Date` class which format to use.
Here is an example:

```
class Date
{
  unsigned int m_month;
  unsigned int m_day;
  unsigned int m_year;
  public:
     enum Format_Type
     {
        Day_Month_Year,
        Month_Day_Year,
     };
     Format_Type  input_format;
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Date& d);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Date& d)
{
    switch (input_format)
    {
      case Month_Day_Year:
      {
         char separator;
         inp >> d.m_month >> separator >> d.m_day >> separator >> m_year;
      }
      break;
    }
    return inp;
}
```

You could make the `Date` class more complex by allowing the User to specify a formatting string.  But that is left as an exercise for the reader.